# useEffect and dispatch with useCallback cause infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

Trying to load products if `isLoading is true`,
However, the request could return empty array as result.
So I could not set `isLoading` to false based on the products

```
  const [products] =  useSelector((state) => [
        state.application.products
    ]);
```

However, if I put `setIsLoading(false)` in the callback of dispatch.

This will cause inf loop which confusing me.

How to solve this problem in a good pattern? Thanks

```
const Products = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true)
  const [products] =  useSelector((state) => [
        state.application.products
    ]);


    const fetchProductsUpHandler = useCallback(async () => {
        const params = {}
        // should I call setIsLoading(false) here?
        // setIsLoading is local context, loadProducts is defined in reducers.
        dispatch(loadProducts()).then(function(){            
            setIsLoading(false)
        });
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isLoading){
            fetchProductsUpHandler();
        }
    }, [isLoading]);


    return (
// is this part causing error?
        <>
                <ProductTable
                    isLoading={isLoading}
                    products={products}
                />

        </>
    );
  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `useEffect()` function is set to run on an update of `isLoading` and `products`. You aren't sharing all your code, so I can't see what is happening behind the scenes, but I am wondering if you are at some point updating the products state as well? I suspect something like this:

1. App loads, `isLoading = true` as the default
2. `useEffect()` triggers, `isLoading` is true so we call `fetchProductsUpHandler()`
3. `dispatch(loadProducts())` runs and `products` gets updated (this is the part I can't see and where I am taking a guess)
4. `useEffect()` triggers because of the `product` change
5. return to step 3 because `isLoading` is still true

If this is correct, the solution would be to take `product` out of the `useEffect()` hook

Comment: ```loadProducts()``` is an action defined in a store..... still triggers inf loop with removing the products.

Comment: is that because i have products and isloading states in my render function?

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to debug the problem, but I haven't played with react hooks much so someone else may see something I don't.

Based on your updates, I would definitely try moving the setIsLoading before the dispatch, though I don't believe it will fix the problem. Never hurts to try it!

As for the render function, what you have shown doesn't look wrong, but it's possible the inf loop is occurring inside the ProductTable module, and we don't have that code visible here.

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern that I find is to have the `isLoading` flag in your redux state. So your code would have something like:

```
const [isLoading] =  useSelector((state) => [
  state.application.isLoading
]);
```

I am assuming your `loadProducts()` is in an action, so there would be the logic to set your `isLoading` to `true` or `false`.

Comment: That action is in other files. **storeSlice** should not touch local states.

Comment: is then render function causing the issue?

Comment: Yes, the action should be in other file. Just like your reducer should be in a different file as well. And if your products array is in the store, than the loading flag could be there too. The loading flag is not a local state, if your products array is a global state. The loading refers to the products, not to your component :)

Comment: @newBike to answer the other question, your render function is fine. And just to add a bit more, there are other ways to do it, like was posted here. Having the loading in the reducer together with the products is one of the common patterns. Since you asked about good patterns, that's why the suggestion :)

Comment: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#displaying-loading-state

Answer (score 0):

The question you have to ask yourself is why do you have isLoading as a dependency for `fetchProductsUpHandler`?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading){
        fetchProductsUpHandler();
    }
}, [isLoading]);
```

You could have put this entirely into a function where you setIsLoading(true), and you can avoid the loop.

```
const onClick = async () => {
   setIsLoading(true)
   await fetchProductsUpHandler()
   setIsLoading(false)
}
```

If it's not a trigger event and you are just loading it once, you could have just removed the dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {

        fetchProductsUpHandler();

}, []);
```

Comment: your suggestion wont work with dispatch... dispatch is always async i believe.

Comment: u can skip last line of suggestion 2, and use suggestion 1 + 3. Your problem comes from you using "isLoading" as a dependency, while in your dispatch logic, you setIsLoading(false), hence, triggering the setLoading again.  There's no reason to trigger useEffect using a loading indicator.